# Variable with malloc inside a thread

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I have a question about pthread, when I create a variable inside a thread with malloc and then pass its pointer to a shared structure, i.e fifo, is the pointer passed by thread-1 will be accessed by thread2 ?

Please note that I have to code for the question above, I'm just trying to understand threading better, the below is just what I'm thinking about. The environment is **pthread**, **c** and **linux**

As far as I know threads are sharing the memory of their parent process, If that's the case the below should be correct.

```
void *thread-1(void *pointer)
{
  int *intp = malloc(4);
  send_to_fifo(intp);
}


void *thread-2(void *pointer)
{
  int *iptr;
  iptr = read_from_fifo();
  do_something(iptr);
  free(iptr);
}
```

Comment: `thread-1`?!? That is not an identifier in c. Use `thread_1` or `thread1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> is the pointer passed by thread-1 will be accessed by thread2 ?

Yes: since all threads operate in a common memory space, this is allowed.

`malloc`, `free`, and other memory management functions are thread-safe by default, unless compiled with `NO_THREADS`.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can do this. However you must be careful to not write to variable when it's used by another thread. You need synchronization.

In your case, you have race condition if the threads are run simultaneously (thread2 not waiting for thread1 to finish): thread2 either execute all it's code before thread1 puts anything to fifo or after that.

Comment: I was thinking about that, if read_from_fifo and send_to_fifo have lock then that should be fine, right?

Comment: Not necessarily - if thread2 executes it's code first then `read_from_fifo` will read form empty fifo (or not, depends on rest of the program), which could lead to problems. Memory allocated in thread1 can be never released then. If `read_from_fifo` waits until something is in fifo it should be okay.