# Why can't I access an array allocated inside a thread after this thread has finished executing?

Tags: c, pthreads, malloc

I am using malloc to allocate memory for an array. I realized that if I use malloc inside a thread and this thread stops executing I cannot access the aforementioned  array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 2
#define N 4

void *threadWithoutMalloc(int *vector)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        vector[i] = i + 1;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *threadWithMalloc(int *vector)
{
    vector = malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        vector[i] = i + 1;
    }
    return NULL;
}


int main()
{
    //Generic stuff
    pthread_t *threads;
    threads = malloc(NUM_THREADS * sizeof(pthread_t));
    int rc;
    long t;
    int **pointer_vector = malloc(N * sizeof(int *));

    //Allocating the vector before entering the thread
    pointer_vector[0] = malloc(sizeof(int)*N);

    rc = pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, (void *)threadWithoutMalloc, pointer_vector[0]);

    if (rc)
    {
        printf("Error! Code %d\n", rc);
    }

    //Allocating the vector inside the thread
    rc = pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, (void *)threadWithMalloc, pointer_vector[1]);

    if (rc)
    {
        printf("Error! Code %d\n", rc);
    }

    //Waiting for the threads to finish executing
    pthread_join(threads[0], NULL);
    pthread_join(threads[1], NULL);

    //This works
    printf("%d\n", pointer_vector[0][0]);

    //This results in a segmentation fault
    printf("%d\n", pointer_vector[1][0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Why does that happen? My current hypothesis is that after a thread runs its course it's memory is freed. However, I am using dynamic allocation, and storing the result in a variable that was declared on `main()`. I just want to understand what is going on a bit better.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537115/variable-with-malloc-inside-a-thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`threadWithMalloc` never sends the address of the allocated storage back to its caller or the main thread. It is declared with a parameter `vector` and then assigns a value to `vector`:

```
vector = malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
```

All this does is change the value of the parameter, which is effectively local to the function. Changing the parameter in the function does not change the argument that was passed in the main routine. Thus, in the main routine `pointer_vector[1]` is not changed.

To fix this, let’s first fix the routine declarations. `pthread_create` takes a parameter of type `void *(*)(void *)`, which is a pointer to a routine taking a `void *` parameter and returning a `void *` result. So the thread routines should be declared as routines taking a `void *` parameter and returning a `void *` result, such as:

```
void *threadWithoutMalloc(void *parameter)
```

Now, inside the routine, `threadWithoutMalloc` wants an `int *`, not a `void *`. We can satisfy that with an assignment:

```
int *vector = parameter;
```

Then, when we create the thread for `threadWithoutMalloc`, we can do it without casting the pointer:

```
rc = pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, threadWithoutMalloc, pointer_vector[0]);
```

Your compiler should have given you warnings about the `pthread_create` code you had—casting a routine to `void *` is a bad sign (and its behavior is not defined by the C standard), and the resulting `void *` also had to be converted by the compiler to the parameter type, `void *(*)(void *)`, which also has behavior not defined by the C standard and is a constraint violation. If your compiler did not give you warnings about that, you should enable more warnings in your compiler.

For `threadWithoutMalloc`, the code above passes it an `int *`, which is fine for something that merely receives an `int *`. For `threadWithMalloc`, we want it to provide us with an `int *`. One way to do this is to pass it a pointer to an `int *`, which gives it the address of space where we want it to store an `int *`. To do this, we can pass it the address of `pointer_vector[1]`:

```
rc = pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, threadWithMalloc, &pointer_vector[1]);
```

Then, it `threadWithMalloc` we again want to fix its declaration:

```
void *threadWithMalloc(void *parameter)
```

and assign the parameter to an object of the desired type:

```
int **vector = parameter;
```

Then, since `vector` is a pointer to where our `int *` will be rather than being the `int *` itself, we change `vector` to `*vector` in the following code:

```
(*vector) = malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
int i;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    (*vector)[i] = i + 1;
}
```

Another way to provide the `int *` to the main thread would be to return it as the return value of `pthreadWithMalloc`. I only used the parameter method to illustrate different types of parameters.